# FastMM and implicit dll delayed

Tags: delphi, dll, external, delay, fastmm

I use delphi XE2 with FastMM4.
When I want to create a DLL with the keyword "Delayed", I've a violation when I leave the application.
If I test without "Delayed" the can leave application without violation

Main code :

```
type
    function Add(X, Y : Integer) : Integer; overload; stdcall external 'MaDll.dll' delayed;
var
   Form3 : TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
   try
      showmessage(IntToStr(Add(10, 5)));
   except
      on e : Exception do
         showmessage(e.Message);
   end;
end;

end.
```

Dll code :

```
library MaDll;

uses
  FastMM4,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

function Add(X, Y : Integer) : Integer; stdcall;
begin
   Result := X + Y
end;

exports
   Add;

begin

end.
```

Does exist a parameter in FastMM ?

Comment: What is a violation? Have you debugged this?

Comment: In debug or not : 
---------------------------
Erreur d'application
---------------------------
Exception EAccessViolation dans le module MaDll.dll en 00020E65.

Violation d'accès à l'adresse 053D0E65 dans le module 'MaDll.dll'. Lecture de l'adresse FFFFFFF8.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: Please use the debugger to work out where this error is raised. It does sound like a Delphi bug though. Testing in later version is another option. Perhaps you'll have to give up on using delayed.

Comment: With the debugger, I've the same problem :-) I pass on the "end." of program and after I enter on the FastMM4.pas and it crashes without stop on a line.

Comment: Hex `FFFFFFF8` is decimal `-8`. The RTL and FastMM are both full of special memory blocks that are negative offsets of a starting address (typically used for memory block tracking data, string attributes, object vtables, etc), so this suggests to me that some piece of code (and debugging would show you what code is located at address `053D0E65`) is using a memory pointer to access such a hidden memory block at a -8 offset, but the pointer itself is `nil`, hense the attempt to access memory address `FFFFFFF8` which fails with an AV.

Comment: Since I have XE2 installed, and since you kindly provided all the code, I built this example.  It does not crash here when I close the application after calling the DLL.  Are you using the default .INC file that comes with FASTMM and do you have any FASTMM options defined?

Comment: You have to include debug info for rtl and fastmm too

Comment: Yes by default it work fine because FastMM doesn't shared memory with DLL. For activate the dll share memory, I've changed these options : -{$define ShareMM} - {$define ShareMMIfLibrary} - {$define AttemptToUseSharedMM}. And the violation is caused by "{$define AttemptToUseSharedMM}".... but I don't understand why...

Comment: If I active {$define NeverUninstall} it work. But I've always a memory leak.